# How to convert any HTML element into SVG using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to convert any html element into svg. I have used following method. it just work for certain extend.

```
     var element = document.getElementById(id);
     var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
     var str = serializer.serializeToString(element);
     var file = new File([str], fileName, {type: "image/svg+xml"})
```

Does any one have idea?

Comment: Use `foreignObject`.